# Convert number to words in db2

Tags: db2

I am using db2.
I have a table which gives a value.
For ex : value=5000

Is there any way in query or something where i can convert the number into a word.

I above example "Five thousand".....

I am using db2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the job which database should do. So the answer is no.

Comment: Technically you *could* do it with a user defined function.  But, I agree with @xdazz, this is not really something that the database engine should be used for.

Comment: Recurisve CTEs would probably help.  But if you need any sort of localization, that goes out the window (because assembly rules are not necessarily uniform).  You will likely be far better off supplying some sort of `LocalizedNumberTranslator` to your display formatter polymorphically, which just accepts a number (and outputs the string).

Answer (score -1):

You could use SELECT CASE, e,g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (YOURFIELD = 5000) THEN 'Five Thousand' ELSE 'Something Else'
```